# Modify my model robot in Gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, p3dx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Ros Users:

I have this P3DX model in gazebo https://github.com/RafBerkvens/ua_ros_p3dx

I would like to add a simple grey box on it. How can I do that? modifying file .xml? or I must do the box in autocad before?

Thanks you so much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213277/modify-my-model-robot-in-gazebo/) by [Alvaro Salcedo](https://answers.ros.org/users/22155/alvaro-salcedo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 149 on 2015-07-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could modify pioneer3dx.xml, add a new `link` like

```
  <link name="simple_grey_box">
    <inertial>
      <mass value="0.01"/>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <inertia ixx="1" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="1" iyz="0" izz="1"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual name="base_visual">
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry name="top_geom">
        <mesh filename="package://p3dx_description/meshes/top.stl"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="TopBlack">
        <color rgba="0.038 0.038 0.038 1.0"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.0 0 0"/>
      <geometry name="pioneer_geom">
        <box size="0.45 0.38 0.01"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
```

There also needs to be a `joint` that makes this `link` the child of an already existing one.

You could replace top.stl with a mesh of your own.  Or make a box generated by urdf instead of loading a mesh.  The gazebo urdf tutorials are the best place to start for understanding the urdf files: http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_urdf

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2015-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alvaro Salcedo](https://answers.ros.org/users/22155/alvaro-salcedo/) on 2015-07-13**:
Thank you so much.
That's the way!